# How to create arrays from array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am a JavaScript beginner and I am trying make two different arrays with values from one main array.

My main array looks like:

```
0: Array(3) [ 2011, 127072.7, 51584 ]
1: Array(3) [ 2012, 125920.3, 59974 ]
2: Array(3) [ 2013, 129305.4, 15468 ]
3: Array(3) [ 2014, 135364, 84554 ]
4: Array(3) [ 2015, 136757, 98754 ]
5: Array(3) [ 2016, 155653.5, 155548 ]
6: Array(3) [ 2017, 164130.5, 284848 ]
```

And i need create two arrays, first looking like:

```
0: Array(2) [ 2011, 127072.7]
1: Array(2) [ 2012, 125920.3]
2: Array(2) [ 2013, 129305.4]
3: Array(2) [ 2014, 135364]
4: Array(2) [ 2015, 136757]
5: Array(2) [ 2016, 155653.5]
6: Array(2) [ 2017, 164130.5]
```

(first and second value)

and second like:

```
0: Array(2) [ 2011, 51584]
1: Array(2) [ 2012, 59974]
2: Array(2) [ 2013, 15468]
3: Array(2) [ 2014, 84554]
4: Array(2) [ 2015, 98754]
5: Array(2) [ 2016, 155548]
6: Array(2) [ 2017, 284848]
```

(first and third value)

I trying splice, filter etc. but I don't know, how to start.

**It is not necessary to write me an exact solution, but only steps how to do it.**

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answers. They work great. I may have one question for the future. Can it be done so that it is not fixed to two fields? But even three, four, etc?

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve here?  It seems likely using an array of objects is the better option.

Comment: Suggestion: instead of having explicit consecutive years in your array, you could have the year be implicit from a given starting point.  Then you only need one scalar starting point, and the year for any element is known based on its array index.  (Only works if your years are always contiguous and in ascending order like this example.  But does nicely simplify from an array of pairs to just an array of primitive numbers.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could take a dynamic approach and get all items of the array after the key value for each new array.

```js
var data = [[2011, 127072.7, 51584], [2012, 125920.3, 59974], [2013, 129305.4, 15468], [2014, 135364, 84554], [2015, 136757, 98754], [2016, 155653.5, 155548], [2017, 164130.5, 284848]],
    [first, second] = data.reduce(
        (r, [k, ...a]) => {
            a.forEach((v, i) => r[i].push([k, v]));
            return r;
        },
        Array.from({ length: Array.isArray(data[0]) ? data[0].length - 1 : 0 }, () => [])
    );

console.log(first);
console.log(second);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a great answer. Can I have a question for the future? Is it possible to make it fixed not only on 2 arrays but also on more?

Comment: you could replace `[first, second]` with `array` and you get arrays with all columns of the data as arrays.

Comment: Instead of that rather slow `r[i] = r[i] || []` you should just use `Array.from({length: (data[0]?.length ?? 1) - 1}, () => [])` for the initial accumulator value

Comment: @Bergi, really faster? what about `if (!r[i]) r[i] = [];`?

Comment: @NinaScholz No, I meant that you're checking if `r[i]` exists in every loop iteration, whereas you could simply create the necessary result arrays outside of the `reduce` call.

Comment: @Bergi, right. please see edit.

Comment: @NinaScholz Thanks! The `|| 1` doesn't really work though if the `data` array is empty - I guess `Array.isArray(data[0]) ? data[0].length-1 : 0)` would be the correct long form

Comment: @Bergi Premature optimization, imo. I liked the first version best

Comment: @Bergi aren't array accesses super fast and run in constant time? as JollyJoker says, I think that's a rather premature optimization

Comment: @Klaycon No, array accesses out of the array bounds are super slow, so "check if already exists" doesn't work well. My comment was not meant to worry about performance, but to prefer clean and predictable (correct) code. I first wrote "rather ugly and slow" before realising that my suggestion that makes dealing with the empty case explicit isn't a real beauty either.

Answer (score 14):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over your data and use some [Array Destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get the desired output:

```js
const data = [
  [ 2011, 127072.7, 51584 ],
  [ 2012, 125920.3, 59974 ],
  [ 2013, 129305.4, 15468 ],
  [ 2014, 135364, 84554 ],
  [ 2015, 136757, 98754 ],
  [ 2016, 155653.5, 155548 ],
  [ 2017, 164130.5, 284848 ]
];

const arr1 = data.map(([year, val]) => ([year, val]));
const arr2 = data.map(([year, _, val]) => ([year, val]));

console.log(arr1);
console.log(arr2);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for a great answer. Can I have a question for the future? Is it possible to make it fixed not only on 2 arrays but also on more?

Comment: @DominikLev In that case you can use answer posted by Nina. It is a good one.

Comment: This can be generalized using [the rest parameter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters#Syntax) to `([year, ...values]) => [year, values[n]]`

Comment: @JollyJoker - you should post that as an answer, that's a really nice and concise generalized solution

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I already did https://stackoverflow.com/a/60166014/7126740

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Array.prototype.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to iterate over the original array's items, then create the new items and push them into new arrays:

```
var original = [[ 2011, 127072.7, 51584 ], [ 2012, 125920.3, 59974 ], [ 2013, 129305.4, 15468 ]]

var array1 = []
var array2 = []

original.forEach(item => {
  array1.push([item[0], item[1]]);
  array2.push([item[0], item[2]]);
});

console.log(array1);
console.log(array2);
```

Output:

[image]

---

Generating our arrays dynamically so the solution works no matter how many items the original arrays have:

```
var original = [
  [2011, 127072.7, 51584, 1, 2, 3],
  [2012, 125920.3, 59974, 4, 5, 6],
  [2013, 129305.4, 15468, 7, 8, 9]
]

// Array of arrays
var myArray = []

// Fill it with empty arrays
for (var i = 0; i < original[0].length - 1; i++)
  myArray.push([])

// Iterate over original
// For each original, insert the first and i-th element into our array of arrays
original.forEach(item => {
  for (var i = 1; i < item.length; i++) {
    myArray[i - 1].push([item[0], item[i]]);
  }
});

console.log(myArray);
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for a great answer. Can I have a question for the future? Is it possible to make it fixed not only on 2 arrays but also on more?

Comment: It's possible to generate the arrays dynamically without knowing in advance how many items the original arrays will have. Take a look at my edited answer :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you have an array of arrays in the beginning. You can [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) this array to two different arrays using [`destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to get each value from the subarrays in a concise way:

```js
const data = [
  [ 2011, 127072.7, 51584 ],
  [ 2012, 125920.3, 59974 ],
  [ 2013, 129305.4, 15468 ],
  [ 2014, 135364, 84554 ],
  [ 2015, 136757, 98754 ],
  [ 2016, 155653.5, 155548 ],
  [ 2017, 164130.5, 284848 ],
];

const array1 = data.map(([first, second, third]) => [first, second]);
const array2 = data.map(([first, second, third]) => [first, third]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(array1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(array2));
```

Answer (score 4):

Loop through the main array and return a new array by using fixed index values to access your child arrays values.

```js
const multiDimArr = [
  [2011, 127072.7, 51584],
  [2012, 125920.3, 59974],
  [2013, 129305.4, 15468],
  [2014, 135364, 84554],
  [2015, 136757, 98754],
  [2016, 155653.5, 155548],
  [2017, 164130.5, 284848],
]

const arr1= multiDimArr.map(x=>[x[0],x[1]]);
const arr2= multiDimArr.map(x=>[x[0],x[2]]);

console.log(arr1)
console.log(arr2)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function reduce as follow which iterates only once:

```js
let matrix = [[ 2011, 127072.7, 51584 ],[ 2012, 125920.3, 59974 ],[ 2013, 129305.4, 15468 ],[ 2014, 135364, 84554 ],[ 2015, 136757, 98754 ],[ 2016, 155653.5, 155548 ],[ 2017, 164130.5, 284848 ]];

let result = matrix.reduce((a, [year, k, v]) => {
  a.second.push([year, k]);
  a.third.push([year, v]);
  return a;
}, {second: [], third: []});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Why the CSS in this answer?

Comment: @JoshuaFox just for expanding the height of the console.

Answer (score 3):

Here you go

```js
let values = [[ 2011, 127072.7, 51584 ],[ 2012, 125920.3, 59974 ],[ 2013, 129305.4, 15468 ],[ 2014, 135364, 84554 ],[ 2015, 136757, 98754 ],[ 2016, 155653.5, 155548 ],[ 2017, 164130.5, 284848 ]];

let chunk1 = values.map(arr1 => {
  return [arr1[0], arr1[1]]
});
let chunk2 = values.map(arr1 => {
  return [arr1[0], arr1[2]]
})

console.log("Chunk 1", chunk1);
console.log("Chunk 2", chunk2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used map for loop, two arrays to push the needed values.

```js
let point_table = []
let integer_table = []
const historical_table = [
  [2011, 127072.7, 51584],
  [2012, 125920.3, 59974],
  [2013, 129305.4, 15468],
  [2014, 135364, 84554],
  [2015, 136757, 98754],
  [2016, 155653.5, 155548],
  [2017, 164130.5, 284848]
]
historical_table.map(row => {
  point_table.push([row[0], row[1]])
  integer_table.push([row[0], row[2]])
})
console.log(point_table, integer_table)
```

Answer (score 1):

For the generic solution, I think building an array of indexes for the value columns gives you a simple way of mapping the full data to the arrays you want.

```
[...data[0].keys()].slice(0,-1)
```

gives you an array of indices, minus the one column that was the year, and

```
n => data.map(([year, ...values]) => [year, values[n]])
```

gives you the array you want for the nth value column. So:

```js
var data = [[2011, 127072.7, 51584], [2012, 125920.3, 59974], [2013, 129305.4, 15468], [2014, 135364, 84554], [2015, 136757, 98754], [2016, 155653.5, 155548], [2017, 164130.5, 284848]]

const yearArrays = arr => [...arr[0].keys()].slice(0,-1)
       .map(arr.map(([year, ...values]) => [year, values[n]]))

console.log(yearArrays(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

another solution :

```
 const original= [  [ 2011, 127072.7, 51584 ], [ 2012, 125920.3, 59974 ],[ 2013, 129305.4, 15468 ],  [ 2014, 135364, 84554 ],  [ 2015, 136757, 98754 ],  [ 2016, 155653.5, 155548 ],  [ 2017, 164130.5, 284848 ]];
```

> original.map(x=> [ [x[0],x[1]] , [x[0],x[2]] ])
>   .reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), [])

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for input arrays of generic length.

```js
const input = [[1,11,111,1111],[2,22,222,2222]];

const result = input.reduce((accumulator, [head, ...tail]) => {
  tail.forEach((item, index) => {
    accumulator[index] = accumulator[index] || [];
    accumulator[index].push([head, item]);
  });
  return accumulator;
}, [])

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this solution to make any generic combination from existing multi dimensional array.
You have to pass the index of items to pick from explicitly and that's what make it generic.

```js
    const multiDimArr = [
      [2011, 127072.7, 51584],
      [2012, 125920.3, 59974],
      [2013, 129305.4, 15468],
      [2014, 135364, 84554],
      [2015, 136757, 98754],
      [2016, 155653.5, 155548],
      [2017, 164130.5, 284848],
    ]


    function arrayCombo (idxA, idxB){
      return multiDimArr.map(x=>[x[idxA],x[idxB]]);
    }

    console.log(arrayCombo(0, 1));
    console.log(arrayCombo(0, 2));
    console.log(arrayCombo(1, 2));
```